# Автоответчик в Contact Form 7 должен срабатывать после паузы N минут

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form7

Суть: В Contact Form 7 есть возможность отправлять автоответ юзеру. Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот автоответ сработал через промежуток времени в N минут после того как юзер кликнет "отправить". Как это реализовать? Есть идеи?

Comment: Через промежуточный почтовый сервис,  настроив там правила. А php не может отложенно работать. Ну те теоретически можно не отправлять а писать в базу, а потом по крону дёргать, но это уже не CF7. Или СF7, с несколькими дополнениями включая собственное - уже для инициации отправки.

Comment: Использование СF7 необязательно. В какой форме и каким образом можно реализовать паузу перед отправкой? Сообщение, которое юзер отправляет мне, тоже нужно задержать на N минут.

Comment: @SeVlad Какой промежуточный сервис обеспечит паузу? В правилах авоответчика Яндекс  отсутствует возможность задержки.

Comment: На промежутках использовать не автоответчик, а отправку по крону. Принял письмо - сформировал ответ - положил "на отправку"  - дёрнул кроном (напр каждые 10 мин). Ессно это можно сделать только на своём сервере. Во всяком случае я в паблике такого не видел.

Comment: Отличная мысль, только реализовать на сервере задержку отправки письма, а автоответ отправлять с Яндекса. Письмо юзера должно сразу сформироваться и поставиться в очередь. Далее крон запустит периодическую задачу.
Задача смотрит что есть не отправленная почта и делает свое дело. Как поставить письмо в очередь?

Answer (score 0):

php не Асинхронный язык праграмирования для етого нужен javascript с помощю function settimeout()
пример

```
function func() {
  //здесь твой логика
}
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

1000-означает 1 секунд

Comment: не могли бы вы более развёрнуто пояснить, в кой файл писать и можно ли сделать рандомное время.

Comment: файл .js сделать рандомное время пример setTimeout(func,Math.random()*10000);

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_random

Comment: так а что помещать внутри функции function func() какой файл править по какому условию и откуда вызывать функцию? в эту форму ничего добавлять не нужно?

Comment: функция вызывает здесь setTimeout(FUNC{{//здесь }}, 1000); внутри функции function func()  твой логика отправлять автоответ юзеру

Comment: где, в каком файле расположен код отправки автоответа в Contact Form 7? работаю, пока, только с формой <label> Ваше имя (обязательно)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Ваш e-mail (обязательно)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Тема
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Сообщение
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Отправить"]

Comment: https://wordpress-book.ru/rusificirovannye/nastrojka-contact-form-7/ смотри структуру Contact Form 7

Comment: знаю структуру самой формы и Опцию "Письмо 2", но как её в функцию function func() поставить?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript полезная ссылка как обеденить JS и WordPress